# iOS version of a OS X core data app

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a fully functional core data OS X application. I now want to make an iOS version. Can I reuse the core data model or do I have to rewrite it from scratch?  I haven't found a lot of commentary on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with some restrictions, like making sure that you have supported types on both platforms.

For example, if you use some type of `NSTransformableAttributeType` objects or use `NSImage/UIImage` saved as binary data, it won't work on both platforms.